# Illegal hardware instruction / Illegal instruction: 4 al ejecutar algunos programas en C++ desde macOS

Tags: c++, macos

Estoy teniendo desde hace unos días este problema y no encuentro una solución. Al realizar programas en C++, al querer ejecutarlos en macOS (Macbook Air early 2015) me salta "Illegal instruction:4 desde 'bash' e "Illegal hardware instruction" desde 'zsh'

```
$ ./matrices < datos_m_3.txt
[1]    71856 illegal hardware instruction  ./matrices < datos_m_3.txt
```

He probado a reinstalar la CLT de Xcode, el compilador gcc, incluso formateé el Mac y con valores de fábrica aún así, me sigue dando este error, cuando nunca me lo ha dado.

*El caso es que en Windows y Linux (Ubuntu) si me ejecuta sin este error, incluso con programas de años anteriores hechos con el mismo Mac, ya no me deja ejecutarlos.

Gracias de antemano.

El código lo tengo distribuido en tres ficheros: un main, un .hpp de cabeceras y un .cpp

main_m_3.cpp

```
#include "matrices_3.hpp"

int main(void)
{
    matrix_t A;
    matrix_t B;

    cout << endl;
    A.read(cin);
    cout << "---  MATRIZ ORIGINAL  ---" << endl;
    A.write();

    cout << "---  PRECISIÓN 0.0001 ---" << endl;
    A.filtra(B,5.254,1E-4);
    B.write();

    cout << "---  PRECISIÓN 0.001  ---" << endl;
    A.filtra(B,5.254,1E-3);
    B.write();

    cout << "---  PRECISIÓN 0.01   ---" << endl;
    A.filtra(B,5.254,1E-2);
    B.write();

    cout << "---  PRECISIÓN 0.1    ---" << endl;
    A.filtra(B,5.254,1E-1);
    B.write();

    cout << "---  PRECISIÓN 1.0    ---" << endl;
    A.filtra(B,5.254,1.0);
    B.write();

    cout << "---  MATRIZ ORIGINAL  ---" << endl;
    A.write();

    cout << "---  MATRIZ ORIGINAL TRASPUESTA---" << endl;
    A.trasponer();
}
```

matrices_3.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdio>       // Cabecera que contendrá el procedimiento sprintf
#include <iostream>     // Cabecera que tendrá la E/S mediante flujo
#include <cmath>        // Cabecera que contendrá las funcioens matemáticas

using namespace std;


//========================================================================================
// Definición de tipos
//========================================================================================


typedef double      matrix_item_t;  

typedef unsigned short int  matrix_inx_t;   

typedef unsigned short int  vector_inx_t;   

class matrix_t {

//========================================================================================
// Atributos privados.
//========================================================================================

private:

    matrix_item_t*  M_; /**< Puntero que apunta al comienzo del vector conteniendo los elementos de la matriz. */

    matrix_inx_t    m_; /**< Número de filas.   */
    matrix_inx_t    n_; /**< Número de columnas.*/



//========================================================================================
// Métodos públicos.
//========================================================================================

public:

    matrix_t(matrix_inx_t m,matrix_inx_t n); 
    matrix_t(void);     
    ~matrix_t(void);

    matrix_item_t get_matrix_item(matrix_inx_t i,matrix_inx_t j) const;

    void set_matrix_item(matrix_inx_t i,matrix_inx_t j,matrix_item_t it);

    matrix_inx_t get_m(void) const;

    matrix_inx_t get_n(void) const;

    istream& read(istream& is);
    ostream& write(ostream& os) const;

    void write(void) const;

    bool igual(matrix_item_t a, matrix_item_t b, double precision);
    bool mayor(matrix_item_t a, matrix_item_t b, double precision); 
    bool menor(matrix_item_t a, matrix_item_t b, double precision);
    bool cuadrado(matrix_item_t a, matrix_item_t b, double precision);
    bool zero(matrix_item_t a, double precision);
    void filtra(matrix_t& M, matrix_item_t it, double precision);
    void trasponer(void);
    void submatrices(void);

//========================================================================================
// Métodos privados.
//========================================================================================

private:

    vector_inx_t pos(matrix_inx_t i,matrix_inx_t j);
    vector_inx_t pos(matrix_inx_t i,matrix_inx_t j) const;

    void crearMatriz(void); 

    void destruirMatriz(void);

    void redimensiona(matrix_inx_t m,matrix_inx_t n);

};
```

matrices_3.cpp

```
    #include "matrices_3.hpp"
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


//========================================================================================
// Métodos privados.
//========================================================================================



vector_inx_t matrix_t::pos(matrix_inx_t i,matrix_inx_t j)
{
    if ((i<1)||(i>m_)||(j<1)||(j>n_)){
        cerr << "Error accediendo a matriz"<< endl;
        return 0;
        }

    return (i-1)*n_+j-1;


}

vector_inx_t matrix_t::pos(matrix_inx_t i,matrix_inx_t j) const
{
    if ((i<1)||(i>m_)||(j<1)||(j>n_)){
        cerr << "Error accediendo a matriz"<< endl;
        return 0;
        }

    return (i-1)*n_+j-1;


}


void matrix_t::crearMatriz(void) 
{
    M_= new matrix_item_t [m_*n_];  // Crea un vector de mxn elementos. 

    if (M_==NULL)       // Si ha fallado la reserva de memoria. 
        cerr << "Error creando matriz." << endl;
}       



void matrix_t::destruirMatriz(void)
{
    if (M_!=NULL){
        delete [] M_;       // Libera la memoria previamente reservada para la matriz.
        M_=NULL;        // Asigna NULL al puntero.
    }

    m_=0;
    n_=0;
}




void matrix_t::redimensiona(matrix_inx_t m,matrix_inx_t n)
{
    destruirMatriz();

    m_=m;
    n_=n;

    crearMatriz();
}




//========================================================================================
// Métodos públicos.
//========================================================================================

matrix_t::matrix_t(matrix_inx_t m,matrix_inx_t n):
M_(NULL),
m_(m),
n_(n)
{
    crearMatriz();
}   




matrix_t::matrix_t(void):
M_(NULL),
m_(0),
n_(0)
{}      



matrix_t::~matrix_t(void)
{
    destruirMatriz();
}


matrix_item_t matrix_t::get_matrix_item(matrix_inx_t i,matrix_inx_t j) const
{
    return M_[pos(i,j)];
}


void matrix_t::set_matrix_item(matrix_inx_t i,matrix_inx_t j,matrix_item_t it)
{
    M_[pos(i,j)]=it;    
}




matrix_inx_t matrix_t::get_m(void) const
{
    return m_;
}




matrix_inx_t matrix_t::get_n(void) const
{
    return n_;
}




istream& matrix_t::read(istream& is)
{
    int m,n;

    is >> m >> n;

    redimensiona(m,n);

    const int sz=m*n;

    for(int i=0;i<sz;i++)
        is >> M_[i];

}



ostream& matrix_t::write(ostream& os) const
{

    os << setw(10) << get_m() << setw(10) << get_n() << endl;

    for(int i=1;i <= get_m();i++){

        for(int j=1;j <= get_n() ;j++)
            os << setw(10) << fixed << setprecision(6) << get_matrix_item(i,j);

        os << endl;
    }
}

void matrix_t::write(void) const 
{


    for(int i=1;i <= get_m();i++){
        cout << "|";
        for(int j=1;j <= get_n();j++)
            cout << setw(10) << fixed << setprecision(6) << get_matrix_item(i,j);
        cout << " |";
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------
//FASE 2
//-----------------------------------------------------
bool matrix_t::igual(matrix_item_t a, matrix_item_t b, double precision)
{
  if (fabs((a-b))<precision) {
   return (true);
  }
  else {
   return (false);
  }
}

bool matrix_t::mayor(matrix_item_t a, matrix_item_t b, double precision)
{
  if ((a-b)>precision) {
   return (true);
  }
  else {
   return (false);
  }
}

bool matrix_t::menor(matrix_item_t a, matrix_item_t b, double precision)
{
  if ((a-b)<-(precision)) {
   return (true);
  }
  else {
   return (false);
  }
}

bool matrix_t::zero(matrix_item_t a, double precision)
{
  if (fabs(a)<precision) {
   return (true);
  }
  else {
   return (false);
  }
}

bool matrix_t::cuadrado(matrix_item_t a, matrix_item_t b, double precision)
{

  if (fabs((a*a)-b)<precision){
   return (true);
  }
  else {
   return (false);
  }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------
//Fase 3
//-----------------------------------------------------
void matrix_t::filtra(matrix_t& M, matrix_item_t it, double precision)
{
  M.redimensiona(get_m(), get_n());
    for (int i=1; i<=get_m(); i++)
      for (int j=1; j<=get_n(); j++){
        if (igual(get_matrix_item(i,j),it,precision))
          M.set_matrix_item(i, j, get_matrix_item(i,j));
        else 
          M.set_matrix_item(i, j,0.0); 
        }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------
//Fase 4
void matrix_t::trasponer(void)
{
    for(int j=1; j<=get_n(); j++){
        cout << "|";
        for(int i = 1; i <=get_m(); i++){ 
            cout << setw(10) << fixed << setprecision(6) << get_matrix_item(i,j);
        }
        cout << " |";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Y a este programa, se le pasa un fichero de texto para con los datos de la matriz.

datos_m_3.txt

```
          5           3 

   5.254560    5.254570    5.254580 
   5.354560    5.254000    5.254100 
   5.654560    5.354570    5.255560 
   5.754560    6.000000    5.354580 
   5.254580    5.300000    5.254590
```

Y por último, este es el Makefile que creé y estoy usando.

```
CXX=g++ 
CXXFLAGS=-g

OBJS = main_m_3.cpp matrices_3.cpp

all: ${OBJS}
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o main ${OBJS}

clear: 
    rm -rf ${OBJS}
```

Comment: ¿Lo compilaste en os x?

Comment: Si, en la terminal con gcc

Comment: Lo compilo con g++ main.cpp matriz.cpp -o matriz, también lo hago a través de un Makefile, lo pruebo de las dos formas

Comment: Listo, editada! Perdonen, soy nuevo por aquí :)

Comment: me late que el problema son los permisos de la Mac. Agrega un "sudo" adelante del comando y quizás funcione

Comment: No, ya lo probé y lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

Prueba especificando tu versión de macOS con el flag

> -mmacosx-version-min=version
>
> ```
> The earliest version of MacOS X that this executable will run on is version. Typical values of version include 10.1, 10.2, and 10.3.9.
>
> If the compiler was built to use the system’s headers by default, then the default for this option is the system version on which the
> ```
>
> compiler is running, otherwise the default is to make choices that are
>   compatible with as many systems and code bases as possible.

Te dejo el enlace porque hay más opciones
[GCC | 3.18.10 Darwin Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Darwin-Options.html)

Comment: Justo lo llevo probando unos días y nada, el flag me sigue sin resolver el problema. Mi versión de macOS es la 10.13.3. Gracias @marcebond